# Menu Dropdown do Bootstrap não funciona em site asp.net

Tags: html5, asp.net, css3

Tenho uma página `index.html` que o recurso do menu dropdown funciona normalmente, mas quando eu migrei para [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) parou de funcionar.

Estou usando uma página `Default.aspx` que herda da `masterpage.master`.

```html
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <a href="Default.aspx" class="btn btn-primary">Home</a>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="QuemSomos.aspx" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Quem Somos</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>   
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            <li><a href="#">Certificações</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Alianças Estratégicas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fala, cara.

1. Certifique-se de que o `jQuery` está sendo carregado;
2. Certifique-se de que o `bootstrap.js` está sendo carregado;
3. Certifique-se de que não ocorre nenhum erro de javascript que impede que o dropdown seja ativado;

Assumindo que o problema não é um dos itens acima:

1. Tente ativar o toggle `dropdown` manualmente no evento `document.ready`.

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar, Alan.
Eu tenho outro recurso na mesma página que funciona, mas esse recurso não funciona.
Eu gostaria de tentar a terceira opção, mas não sei como fazer.
Obrigado.

Comment: Como eu faço para testar a 3ª opção?
Obrigado.

Comment: Olá, Fabricio.
Provavelmente você tem algum código jquery ativado no evento document.ready.
Se não tiver, coloque o trecho abaixo antes do fechamento da tag body (</body>):
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
</script>

Comment: Funcionou Alan.
Muito obrigado. 
Deus lhe abençoe.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi o código funciona normalmente.

http://jsfiddle.net/moykn/Lz82E/

Certifique se, além do que já foi citado pelo Alan R., de que o Jquery também esteja sendo carregado inclusive antes do próprio Bootstrap.

Comment: Moykn.
Esse link é muito útil para efetuar testes.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Tive o mesmo problema em meu layout,ao utilizar o inspector do Google chromer para verificar se tinha algum erro em meu código, fui informado da versão que estava utilizando do jquery não era compatível, que deveria usar da versão do jquery 1.9.1 em diante,mudei e o meu problema foi resolvido, espero ajudar.